# BigQuery SQL - adding new record to existing record

Tags: google-bigquery

I have two tables I want to create a UNION of, but they do not have the same schema.

Table 1 looks like this:
[Table 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ldoON.png)

Table 2 looks like this:
[Table 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9XUxE.png)

How can I select all data for Table 2 and add a record for details.employment.locations city,regionCode, and Formatted. I want to just include null values for all of them using BigQuery SQL.

Thank you,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work. I have created ctes for table1 as table2 as per your schema. Since you have tables in place you can start your query from **UNIONED** cte

```
WITH  TABLE1 AS
(
SELECT 
        'WEBSITE 1' AS WEBSITE,
        STRUCT (
                STRUCT ('NAME 1 ') AS NAME,
                STRUCT ('AGE 1') AS AGE,
                'GENDER' AS GENDER,
                STRUCT(
                        'EMPLOYEMENT NAME 1' AS NAME,
                        FALSE AS _CURRENT,
                        'EMPLOYEMENT TITLE 1' AS TITLE,
                        STRUCT(
                                'EMPLOYEMENT LOCATION 1' AS CITY,
                                'EMPLOYEMENT REGION_CODE 1' AS REGION_CODE,
                                'EMPLOYEMENT FORMATTED 1' AS FORMATTED
                        ) AS LOCATION
                ) AS EMPLOYEMENT
                
        ) AS DETAILS
)
, TABLE2 AS 
(
        SELECT 
        'WEBSITE 1' AS WEBSITE,
        STRUCT (
                STRUCT ('NAME 2') AS NAME,
                STRUCT ('AGE 2') AS AGE,
                'GENDER' AS GENDER,
                STRUCT(
                        'EMPLOYEMENT NAME 2' AS NAME,
                        FALSE AS _CURRENT,
                        'EMPLOYEMENT TITLE 2' AS TITLE
                ) AS EMPLOYEMENT
                
        ) AS DETAILS
)
,UNIONED AS
(
SELECT  WEBSITE,
        DETAILS.NAME AS NAME,
        DETAILS.AGE AS AGE,
        DETAILS.GENDER AS GENDER,
        DETAILS.EMPLOYEMENT.NAME AS EMPLOYEMENT_NAME,
        DETAILS.EMPLOYEMENT._CURRENT AS EMPLOYEMENT_CURRENT,
        DETAILS.EMPLOYEMENT.TITLE AS EMPLOYEMENT_TITLE,
        DETAILS.EMPLOYEMENT.LOCATION.CITY AS EMPLOYEMENT_LOCATION_CITY,
        DETAILS.EMPLOYEMENT.LOCATION.REGION_CODE AS EMPLOYEMENT_LOCATION_REGION_CODE,
        DETAILS.EMPLOYEMENT.LOCATION.FORMATTED AS EMPLOYEMENT_LOCATION_FORMATTED,
FROM TABLE1 
UNION ALL 
SELECT  WEBSITE,
        DETAILS.NAME,
        DETAILS.AGE,
        DETAILS.GENDER,
        DETAILS.EMPLOYEMENT.NAME,
        DETAILS.EMPLOYEMENT._CURRENT,
        DETAILS.EMPLOYEMENT.TITLE,
        NULL ,
        NULL,
        NULL
FROM TABLE2
)
SELECT 
        WEBSITE,
        STRUCT (
                STRUCT (U.NAME ) AS NAME,
                STRUCT (U.AGE) AS AGE,
                U.GENDER,
                STRUCT (
                        U.EMPLOYEMENT_NAME AS NAME,
                        U.EMPLOYEMENT_CURRENT AS _CURRENT,
                        U.EMPLOYEMENT_TITLE AS TITLE,
                        STRUCT (
                                U.EMPLOYEMENT_LOCATION_CITY AS CITY,
                                U.EMPLOYEMENT_LOCATION_REGION_CODE  AS REGION_COD,
                                U.EMPLOYEMENT_LOCATION_FORMATTED  AS FORMATTED
                        ) AS LOCATION

                ) AS EMPLOYMENT
        ) AS DETAILS
FROM  UNIONED AS U
```

Comment: Thank you! This was not the exact solution I ended up using but helped me immensely

Comment: Welcome, can you share your approach? It would be a learning for SO audience.